# collect data from Jenkins pipeline parallel steps

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

What would be the best way to collect data (such as pass/fail results) from parallel steps.

What I've reached so far:

```
#!groovy
def fspam(name, spam){
    spam[name] = "BEEN THERE TOO"
}

// pipeline
node('slave'){
    stage("test"){
        targets = ["a", "b"]
        def tasks = [:] 
        def spam = [:]
        targets.each{ tasks["${it}"] = {
            node('slave'){
                echo "dry-run ${it}"
                spam[it] = "BEEN THERE" <--- works
                fspam(it)         <--- fails
            } 
        } 

        }
        parallel tasks
        print("spam")
        print(spam)
    }
}
```

But it failed with:

> Also:   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: stam
>   for class: WorkflowScript groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No
>   such property: stam for class: WorkflowScript     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)

1. Seems that in-closure it populates the map successfully, but when using function it throws error
2. I don't sure having a global map is the best/cleanest way

**Any suggestions**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [.asSynchronized()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#asSynchronized()):

```
targets = ["a", "b"]

tasks = [:]
spam = [:].asSynchronized()

targets.each { target ->
    tasks[target] = {
        echo "dry-run ${target}"
        spam[target] = "BEEN THERE"
        fspam(target, spam)         // <--- passing spam fixes the issue
    } 
}

parallel tasks

print("spam")
print(spam)
```

This guarantees that updates to the map are thread-safe.  For collecting a list, you can use `[].asSynchronized()`.  [Link](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#asSynchronized())

Comment: Great! thank you.
However, note that this method is not whitelisted for jenkins sandbox

Comment: @Vano Please see https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Script+Security+Plugin paragraph beginning "But you are not limited to the default whitelist..."

Answer (score 1):

Well, missed an obvious solution:

```
#!groovy
def fspam(name, spam){
    spam[name] = "BEEN THERE TOO"
}

// pipeline
node('slave'){
    stage("test"){
        targets = ["a", "b"]
        def tasks = [:] 
        def spam = [:]
        targets.each{ tasks["${it}"] = {
            node('slave'){
                echo "dry-run ${it}"
                spam[it] = "BEEN THERE"
                fspam(it, spam)         <--- passing spam fixes the issue
            } 
        } 

        }
        parallel tasks
        print("spam")
        print(spam)
    }
}
```

one question remains: **is there better/cleaner way?**(thread safety/jenkins pipeline native, etc)